# Обратиться к transcluded элементу. Angular 1.5

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Делаю кастомную всплывающую подсказку для различных длинных тестовых блоков (например, комментарии/описание).

Работает она следующим образом:
На странице выводится краткий текст, при нажатии на этот текст появляется окошко, где уже полное описание.

Структура моей всплывающей подсказки следующая:

```
<custom-tooltip>
    <title></title>
    <description></description>
</custom-tooltip>
```

Где `<title>` и `<description>` - tranclude элементы.

Вся задумка в дом, что по дефолту в title выводится обрезанный description, который я туда скормлю, а description содержит полное описание, просто изначально скрыто. Но при нажатии на этот title должен появляться description.

Вопрос: как внутри directive обратиться к моему trancluded description, чтобы подключать/отключать класс видимости?

Привожу макет кода:

```
app.directive('customTooltip', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    transclude: {
      'title': '?title',
      'description': '?description'
    },
    templateUrl: 'tooltip.html',
    link: function TooltipCtrl($scope, $element, $attrs) {

  $element.bind('click', function(e) {
    openFull();
  });

  function openFull() {
    //Здесь надо получить необходимый элемент с описанием
  }
}
  };
});
```

Я пока додумался только до использования $element.children(), но мне почему то кажется, что есть более правильный вариант.

Рабочий пример находится [здесь](http://plnkr.co/edit/7rEob6UciTQd3DFHtEuR?p=preview)

Comment: можешь сделать рабочий пример на [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue)?

Comment: @Grundy рабочий пример сделал. Вопрос уточняю: там нужная мне "всплывашка" находится через getElementById - я же хочу обратиться при помощи scope самой директивы, как бы. Т.е. не держать айдишник, а работать только с тем, что у меня есть в рамках scope.

Comment: да, похоже достаточно воспользоваться `ng-class` как советуют в ответе. В примере по ссылке есть атрибут `source`, а в примере тут - нет. Это была попытка что-то обойти? или так и задумывалось брать данные из этого атрибута, а не элементов?

Comment: @Grundy это просто процесс расширения функционала. В примере тут, как вы правильно заметили, sourcе'a нет, но он был добавлен позднее. Атрибут используется для скармливания данных. Т.е. вот у меня есть огромная простыня комментария - вывести надо небольшую часть, а при клике показать уже всю: я отдаю директиве весь текст через атрибут source, далее его там уже обрезаю и вывожу, как хочу.

Comment: Я просто тогда не совсем понимаю смысл в `transclude`, если эти элементы не используются,а все берется из атрибута

Comment: @Grundy ну... в приложении есть несколько мест, где шаблон выводимого текста несколько отличается. Благодаря transclude я могу переделать блок description. Либо же, есть место, где мне в качестве short_name нужно выводить не обрезанный комментарий, а просто какой-нибудь заголовок кастомный. В этом случае помогает transclude для title

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41244/discussion-between-grundy-and-mr-brightside).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может это вам поможет?
ngClass - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass.
А еще лучше глянуть в той же документации ngIf или ngShow.

Comment: Да, видимо это то, чем придётся воспользоваться. Я представлял, что в ангуляре есть какой-нибудь инструмент для работы с элементами, для которых я делаю transclude. Если быть совсем точным - он есть, но мне нужно задавать мой шаблон прямо в директиве и использовать compile. В случае же, когда шаблон берётся из отдельной html-ки, такая штука не пройдёт. Ответ принимаю, спасибо =)

Comment: @Mr.Brightside, _В случае же, когда шаблон берётся из отдельной html-ки, такая штука не пройдёт._ - почему? всегда можно загрузить этот шаблон и скормить его сервису `$compile`.

Comment: @Grundy этого не знал =( а где можно подсмотреть примеры? Т.е. так, чтобы вот у меня для title свой compile, у description - свой